# Node - Show only 1 item while using HTML code in map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-literals

I wanna send a email with node like this:

```
from: "abc@gmail.com",  
to: "test@gmail.com",  
subject: "test",  
html: <p>Message</p>
```

This works fine but when i wanna map some data in the html input it shows only the last item (quantity)

```
<div style="color: #f59e0b;">${cartItems.map((item) => {
 return item.name, item.quantity;
 })}
</div>
```

If I use html inside the template-literals I get an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

```
${cartItems.map((item) => {
return(
 <div>
     <div style='color: #fff;'> item.name</div>
     <div style='color: #fff;'> item.name</div>
 </div>
)
})}
```

Comment: You can't return two items with a return statement. Either put them in an array, or use the map function twice. You also can't use template literals inside a sub-function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `${}` you kind of disable the string temporarily, so HTML syntax doesn't make sense

```
${cartItems.map((item) => {
return(`
 <div>
     <div style='color: #fff;'> ${item.name}</div>
     <div style='color: #fff;'> ${item.name}</div>
 </div>
`)
})}
```